# Does scikit-learn pipeline.fit overrides or update weights when run through k-fold

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Sorry for my ignorance I need to train classifier with cross validation. Will `scikit-learn pipeline.fit` overrides or updates weights when run through k-fold as mentioned below?

```
  pipeline = Pipeline([('count_vectorizer',CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),
                                             token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b',min_df=1)),
                       ('classifier',  MultinomialNB()) ])

for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
    train_text = corpus.iloc[train_indices]['clean_text'].values
    train_y = corpus.iloc[train_indices]['class'].values

    test_text = corpus.iloc[test_indices]['clean_text'].values
    test_y = corpus.iloc[test_indices]['class'].values

    pipeline.fit(train_text, train_y)
    predictions = pipeline.predict(test_text)
```

Comment: It will not update, it will refit the new data.